# What is your experience with non-recursive make?

Tags: build-process, makefile

A few years ago, I read the [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) paper and implemented the idea in my own build process.  Recently, I read another article with ideas about how to [implement non-recursive `make`](http://sites.e-advies.nl/nonrecursive-make.html).  So I have a few data points that non-recursive `make` works for at least a few projects.

But I'm curious about the experiences of others.  Have you tried non-recursive `make`?  Did it make things better or worse?  Was it worth the time?

Comment: In case it's useful to anyone: The link to the "Implementing non-recursive make" paper in the question now 404s, but the paper can be found at what I think is [the author's new website](http://sites.e-advies.nl/nonrecursive-make.html).

Comment: Oh, and it seems [this](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) may be a better place to find "Recursive Make Considered Harmful".

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: Thanks for finding those links! I edited them into the post. (Out of curiosity, would it have helped if the edit function were more prominent or are you reluctant to edit other people's posts? I'm trying to get an idea of how we might improve the site. Hazard of [the job](https://jlericson.com/2019/05/02/community_product_manager.html) ;-)

Comment: Heh. Actually I forgot I had enough rep on SO to do that here. I have no problem editing other people's posts, and I'm a mod on another Stack Exchange site. My apologies for doing the stupid thing rather than the sensible thing.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: No problem! I've just been thinking about why editing isn't used sometimes. (And I didn't notice you were a mod! Now I'm embarrassed. ;-)

Comment: I am trying to do this **again** and [this page](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/) was not coming up in hits.  In particular, [multi-arch builds](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/multi-architecture-builds/) is very useful for many projects and needs to hook into the non-recursive structure.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

We use a non-recursive GNU Make system in the company I work for.  It's based on Miller's paper and especially the "Implementing non-recursive make" link you gave.  We've managed to refine Bergen's code into a system where there's no boiler plate at all in subdirectory makefiles.  By and large, it works fine, and is much better than our previous system (a recursive thing done with GNU Automake).

We support all the "major" operating systems out there (commercially): AIX, HP-UX, Linux, OS X, Solaris, Windows, even the AS/400 mainframe.  We compile the same code for all of these systems, with the platform dependent parts isolated into libraries.

There's more than two million lines of C code in our tree in about 2000 subdirectories and 20000 files.  We seriously considered using SCons, but just couldn't make it work fast enough.  On the slower systems, Python would use a couple of dozen seconds just parsing in the SCons files where GNU Make did the same thing in about one second.  This was about three years ago, so things may have changed since then.  Note that we usually keep the source code on an NFS/CIFS share and build the *same* code on multiple platforms.  This means it's even slower for the build tool to scan the source tree for changes.

Our non-recursive GNU Make system is not without problems.  Here are some of biggest hurdles you can expect to run into:

- Making it portable, especially to Windows, is a lot of work.
- While GNU Make is almost a usable functional programming language, it's not suitable for programming in the large.  In particular, there are no namespaces, modules, or anything like that to help you isolate pieces from each other.  This can cause problems, although not as much as you might think.

The major wins over our old recursive makefile system are:

- It's **fast**.  It takes about two seconds to check the entire tree (2k directories, 20k files) and either decide it's up to date or start compiling.  The old recursive thing would take more than a minute to do nothing.
- It handles dependencies correctly.  Our old system relied on the order subdirectories were built etc.  Just like you'd expect from reading Miller's paper, treating the whole tree as a single entity is really the right way to tackle this problem.
- It's portable to all of our supported systems, after all the hard work we've poured into it.  It's pretty cool.
- The abstraction system allows us to write very concise makefiles.  A typical subdirectory which defines just a library is just two lines.  One line gives the name of the library and the other lists the libraries this one depends on.

Regarding the last item in the above list.  We ended up implementing a sort of macro expansion facility within the build system.  Subdirectory makefiles list programs, subdirectories, libraries, and other common things in variables like PROGRAMS, SUBDIRS, LIBS.  Then each of these are expanded into "real" GNU Make rules.  This allows us to avoid much of the namespace problems.  For example, in our system it's fine to have multiple source files with the same name, no problem there.

In any case, this ended up being a lot of work.  If you can get SCons or similar working for your code, I'd advice you look at that first.

Comment: I don't think any build-system out there can really match a properly written non-recursive GNU make system.

Comment: @JesperE, try tup, and be surprised http://gittup.org/tup/make_vs_tup.html and of course, Premake and cmake generate makefiles automatically, so I assume they can match it by definition.

Comment: @Ville, I'm convinced that making non-recursive make is possible. But I'm not convinced it's maintainable. Did you have to use `sed` for the makefiles? How much boilerplate did you need to use in order to "include" a certain subproject? How easy it is to compile a single subproject alone? Did you put the output files (.c,.d) in a separate directory than the source files?

Comment: @Elazar: I did try `tup`, and it actually was quite impressive. Particularly interesting is the approach to observing how tools interact with the file system.

Comment: @Elazar, boilderplate for including a subproject (directory) was nothing more than mentioning the directory name in the SUBDIRS variable. Compiling a single subproject was a matter of cd'ing to the directory and running "make" there - but it would still rebuild dependencies in other directories if needed. A separate object tree for output was supported and recommended. No sed'ing or other preprocessing for subdirectory makefiles was needed. The makefiles were quite maintainable, but the GNU Make code which implemented everything... not so much.

Comment: @Ville, care to share the code? I'd love to read that. But I actually meant the GNU Make code and asked the wrong questions. The real question is, if I now require to preprocess C files in a certain directory before compiling it, how easy it is to do that.

Comment: @Elazar, sorry, I have no rights to the code, and I don't even work for the same company anymore.  Preprocessing C files can be done with a normal GNU Make rule, only the paths will be different compared to a traditional rules because the files are not in the current working directory.

Comment: @Ville, yeah, but I meant how difficult is it to integrate it with your system (ie, have the processed C files written into the temporary object directory, etc).

Comment: @VilleLaurikari I take it by their absence that you didn't use autotools for this, right? Why? I spent a while working on it, and it seems that non-recursive autotools is to non-recunsive make what recursive autotools is to recursive make. I.e. more automatic.

Comment: Here is the example of non-recursive GNU-make based build system https://github.com/igagis/prorab/blob/master/wiki/HomePage.md

Comment: @JesperE (or others): Any updates on this in 2019?

Answer (score 31):

After reading the RMCH paper, I set out with the goal of writing a proper non-recursive Makefile for a small project I was working on at the time. After I finished, I realized that it should be possible to create a generic Makefile "framework" which can be used to very simply and concisely tell make what final targets you would like to build, what kind of targets they are (e.g. libraries or executables) and what source files should be compiled to make them.

After a few iterations I eventually created just that: a single boilerplate Makefile of about 150 lines of GNU Make syntax that never needs any modification -- it just works for any kind of project I care to use it on, and is flexible enough to build multiple targets of varying types with enough granularity to specify exact compile flags for each source file (if I want) and precise linker flags for each executable. For each project, all I need to do is supply it with small, separate Makefiles that contain bits similar to this:

```
TARGET := foo

TGT_LDLIBS := -lbar

SOURCES := foo.c baz.cpp

SRC_CFLAGS   := -std=c99
SRC_CXXFLAGS := -fstrict-aliasing
SRC_INCDIRS  := inc /usr/local/include/bar
```

A project Makefile such as the above would do exactly what you'd expect: build an executable named "foo", compiling foo.c (with CFLAGS=-std=c99) and baz.cpp (with CXXFLAGS=-fstrict-aliasing) and adding "./inc" and "/usr/local/include/bar" to the `#include` search path, with final linking including the "libbar" library. It would also notice that there is a C++ source file and know to use the C++ linker instead of the C linker. The framework allows me to specify a lot more than what is shown here in this simple example.

The boilerplate Makefile does all the rule building and automatic dependency generation required to build the specified targets. All build-generated files are placed in a separate output directory hierarchy, so they're not intermingled with source files (and this is done without use of VPATH so there's no problem with having multiple source files that have the same name).

I've now (re)used this same Makefile on at least two dozen different projects that I've worked on. Some of the things I like best about this system (aside from how easy it is to create a *proper* Makefile for any new project) are:

- It's *fast*. It can virtually instantly tell if anything is out-of-date.
- 100% reliable dependencies. There is zero chance that parallel builds will mysteriously break, and it always builds *exactly* the minimum required to bring everything back up-to-date.
- I will *never* need to rewrite a complete makefile again :D

Finally I'd just mention that, with the problems inherent in recursive make, I don't think it would have been possible for me to pull this off. I'd probably have been doomed to rewriting flawed makefiles over and over again, trying in vain to create one that actually worked properly.

Comment: And will you show us your 150 lines base makefile?

Comment: @zxcat: See http://github.com/dmoulding/boilermake. To use it, you must supply main.mk (and any other submakefiles that you want to provide). See the README and MANUAL files for more information. The test-app directory has a sample main.mk and other submakefiles that build a simple and silly little test program. Have fun.

Comment: Your makefile looks impressive! Correct me if I'm wrong, but it doesn't make shared objects, right? Or better say, both shared objects and static library at the same time

Comment: @Shahbaz It can make shared objects. Your own submakefiles must tell it what CFLAGS/CXXFLAGS and LDFLAGS should be used when building a shared object. This is because shared object building, unlike static archive creation, is non-standard and entirely platform dependent. You can do both static and shared, by making two submakefiles; let's call them "static.mk" and "shared.mk". In "static.mk", specify `TARGET=libfoo.a` and CFLAGS/LDFLAGS appropriate for a static library. In "shared.mk" specify `TARGET=libfoo.so.x.y` and CFLAGS/LDFLAGS appropriate for a shared object (e.g. -fPIC, -shared).

Comment: @DanMoulding, the problem is where the .o files are put. The thing is that if you build `a.o` out of `a.c` using static CFLAGS, then when making the shared object the Makefile would think `a.o` is already up-to-date, while in reality it needs to be compiled again (with `-fPIC`). So you would need separate directories for objects of static and shared library.

Comment: @Shahbaz You are absolutely right, but the Makefile handles this correctly. The .o files for libfoo.a will go under `build/libfoo.a/` and the .o files for libfoo.so.x.y will go under `build/libfoo.so.x.y/` and each source file will therefore be compiled twice (once with `-fPIC` and once without it).

Comment: @DanMoulding, that's great! Nice work

Comment: How does it handle a directory structure where there are directories without targets?

Comment: Here is another example of non-recursive build system https://github.com/igagis/prorab/blob/master/wiki/TutorialBasicConcepts.md

Answer (score 19):

Let me stress one argument of Miller's paper: When you start to manually resolve dependency relationships between different modules and have a hard time to ensure the build order, you are effectively reimplementing the logic the build system was made to solve in the first place. **Constructing reliable recursive make build systems is very hard.** Real life projects have many interdependent parts whose build order is non-trivial to figure out and thus, this task should be left to the build system. However, it can only resolve that problem if it has global knowledge of the system.

Furthermore, recursive make build-systems are prone to fall apart when building concurrently on multiple processors/cores. While these build systems may seem to work reliably on a single processor, many missing dependencies go undetected until you start to build your project in parallel. I've worked with a recursive make build system which worked on up to four processors, but suddenly crashed on a machine with two quad-cores. Then I was facing another problem: These **concurrency issues** are next to impossible to debug and I ended up drawing a flow-chart of the whole system to figure out what went wrong.

To come back to your question, I find it hard to think of good reasons why one wants to use recursive make. The runtime performance of non-recursive GNU Make build systems is hard to beat and, quite the contrary, many recursive make systems have serious performance problems (weak parallel build support is again a part of the problem). There is a [paper](http://www.genode-labs.com/publications/scons-vs-make-2008.pdf) in which I evaluated a specific (recursive) Make build system and compared it to a SCons port. The performance results are not representative because the build system was very non-standard, but in this particular case the SCons port was actually faster.

Bottom line: If you really want to use Make to control your software builds, go for non-recursive Make because it makes your life far easier in the long run. Personally, I would rather use SCons for usability reasons (or Rake - basically any build system using a modern scripting language and which has implicit dependency support).

Comment: The concurrency issue is biting me on a a project I work with right now. I've been able to activate GNU make's concurrency *inside* modules, but I would have to deal with the intermodule relationships by hand if I wanted concurrency between modules. As a result I get watch a 16 core machine average less than two active cores while building this beast for more than forty minutes. Gah!

Answer (score 10):

I made a half-hearted attempt at my previous job at making the build system (based on GNU make) completely non-recursive, but I ran into a number of problems:

- The artifacts (i.e. libraries and executables built) had their sources spread out over a number of directories, relying on vpath to find them
- Several source files with the same name existed in different directories
- Several source files were shared between artifacts, often compiled with different compiler flags
- Different artifacts often had different compiler flags, optimization settings, etc.

One feature of GNU make which simplifies non-recursive use is **target-specific variable values**:

```
foo: FOO=banana
bar: FOO=orange
```

This means that when building target "foo", $(FOO) will expand to "banana", but when building target "bar", $(FOO) will expand to "orange".

One limitation of this is that it is not possible to have target-specific VPATH definitions, i.e. there is no way to uniquely define VPATH individually for each target. This was necessary in our case in order to find the correct source files.

The main missing feature of GNU make needed in order to support non-recursiveness is that it lacks **namespaces**. Target-specific variables can in a limited manner be used to "simulate" namespaces, but what you really would need is to be able to include a Makefile in a sub-directory using a local scope.

EDIT: Another very useful (and often under-used) feature of GNU make in this context is the macro-expansion facilities (see the [eval](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html#Eval-Function) function, for example). This is very useful when you have several targets which have similar rules/goals, but differ in ways which cannot be expressed using regular GNU make syntax.

Comment: Useful: yes.  Maintainable: no.

Comment: This is years old, but you mention target-specific variables... *danger, Will Robinson!* These don't do what you expect! When building `foo`, `FOO` will be set for both `foo` *and all prerequisites built by `foo`*. So if `foo` and `bar` bother depend on `baz`, whether `baz` is built with `FOO=orange` or `FOO=banana` depends on whether make sees `foo` or `bar` first. This ends up subtly breaking parallel builds, which tend to be non-deterministic.

Comment: I would not recommend GNU make as build tool under any circumstance today.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with the statements in the refered article, but it took me a long time to find a good template which does all this and is still easy to use.

Currenty I'm working on a small research project, where I'm experimenting with continuous integration; automatically unit-test on pc, and then run a system test on a (embedded) target. This is non-trivial in make, and I've searched for a good solution. Finding that make is still a good choice for portable multiplatform builds I finally found a good starting point in http://code.google.com/p/nonrec-make

This was a true relief. Now my makefiles are

- very simple to modify (even with limited make knowledge)
- fast to compile
- completely checking (.h) dependencies with no effort

I will certainly also use it for the next (big) project (assuming C/C++)

Answer (score 8):

I have developed a non-recursive make system for a one medium sized C++ project, which is intended for use on unix-like systems (including macs). The code in this project is all in a directory tree rooted at a src/ directory. I wanted to write a non-recursive system in which it is possible to type "make all" from any subdirectory of the top level src/ directory in order to compile all of the source files in the directory tree rooted at the working directory, as in a recursive make system. Because my solution seems to be slightly different from others I have seen, I'd like to describe it here and see if I get any reactions.

The main elements of my solution were as follows:

1) Each directory in the src/ tree has a file named sources.mk. Each such file defines a makefile variable that lists all of the source files in the tree rooted at the directory. The name of this variable is of the form [directory]_SRCS, in which [directory] represents a canonicalized form of the path from the top level src/ directory to that directory, with backslashes replaced by underscores. For example, the file src/util/param/sources.mk defines a variable named util_param_SRCS that contains a list of all source files in src/util/param and its subdirectories, if any. Each sources.mk file also defines a variable named [directory]_OBJS that contains a list of the the corresponding object file *.o targets. In each directory that contains subdirectories, the sources.mk includes the sources.mk file from each of the subdirectories, and concatenates the [subdirectory]_SRCS variables to create its own [directory]_SRCS variable.

2) All paths are expressed in sources.mk files as absolute paths in which the src/ directory is represented by a variable $(SRC_DIR). For example, in the file src/util/param/sources.mk, the file src/util/param/Componenent.cpp would be listed as $(SRC_DIR)/util/param/Component.cpp. The value of $(SRC_DIR) is not set in any sources.mk file.

3) Each directory also contains a Makefile. Every Makefile includes a global configuration file that sets the value of the variable $(SRC_DIR) to the absolute path to the root src/ directory.  I chose to use a symbolic form of absolute paths because this appeared to be the easiest way to create multiple makefiles in multiple directories that would interpret paths for dependencies and targets in the same way, while still allowing one to move the entire source tree if desired, by changing the value of $(SRC_DIR) in one file. This value is set automatically by a simple script that the user is instructed to run when the package is dowloaded or cloned from the git repository, or when the entire source tree is moved.

4) The makefile in each directory includes the sources.mk file for that directory. The "all" target for each such Makefile lists the [directory]_OBJS file for that directory as a dependency, thus requiring compilation of all of the source files in that directory and its subdirectories.

5) The rule for compiling *.cpp files create a dependency file for each source file, with a suffix *.d, as a side-effect of compilation, as described here: http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html. I chose to use the gcc compiler for dependency generation, using the -M option. I use gcc for dependency generation even when using another compiler to compile the source files, because gcc is almost always available on unix-like systems, and because this helps standardize this part of the build system. A different compiler can be used to actually compile the source files.

6) The use of absolute paths for all files in the _OBJS and _SRCS variables required that I write a script to edit the dependency files generated by gcc, which creates files with relative paths. I wrote a python script for this purpose, but another person might have used sed. The paths for dependencies in the resulting dependency files are literal absolute paths. This is fine in this context because the dependency files (unlike the sources.mk files) are generated locally and rather than being distributed as part of the package.

7) The Makefile in each director includes the sources.mk file from the same directory, and contains a line "-include $([directory]_OBJS:.o=.d)" that attempts to include a dependency files for every source file in the directory and its subdirectories, as described in the URL given above.

The main difference between this an other schemes that I have seen that allow "make all" to be invoked from any directory is the use of absolute paths to allow the same paths to be interpreted consistently when Make is invoked from different directories. As long as these paths are expressed using a variable to represent the top level source directory, this does not prevent one from moving the source tree, and is simpler than some alternative methods of achieving the same goal.

Currently, my system for this project always does an "in-place" build: The object file produced by compiling each source file is placed in the same directory as the source file. It would be straightforward to enable out-of place builds by changing the script that edits the gcc dependency files so as to replace the absolute path to the src/ dirctory by a variable $(BUILD_DIR) that represents the build directory in the expression for the object file target in the rule for each object file.

Thus far, I've found this system easy to use and maintain. The required makefile fragments are short and comparatively easy for collaborators to understand.

The project for which I developed this system is written in completely self-contained ANSI C++ with no external dependencies. I think that this sort of homemade non-recursive makefile system is a reasonable option for self-contained, highly portable code. I would consider a more powerful build system such as CMake or gnu autotools, however, for any project that has nontrivial dependencies on external programs or libraries or on non-standard operating system features.

Answer (score 7):

I know of at least one large scale project ([ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/)), which [advertises using [powerpoint link]](http://www-root.fnal.gov/root2001/presentations/session1/WhatElse.ppt) the mechanism described in Recursive Make Considered Harmful. The framework exceeds a million lines of code and compiles quite smartly.

---

And, of course, all the largish projects I work with that *do* use recursive make are painfully slow to compile. ::sigh::

Comment: interesting. I looked into it and I made an interesting observation that they use CMake instead of GNU make: https://d35c7d8c.web.cern.ch/building-root

Answer (score 0):

I written a not very good non-recursive make build system, and since then a very clean modular recursive make build system for a project called [Pd-extended](http://puredata.info/docs/developer/GettingPdSource).  Its basically kind of like a scripting language with a bunch of libraries included.  Now I'm also working Android's non-recursive system, so that's the context of my thoughts on this topic.

I can't really say much about the differences in performance between the two, I haven't really paid attention since full builds are really only ever done on the build server.  I am usually working either on the core language, or a particular library, so I am only interested in building that subset of the whole package.  The recursive make technique has the huge advantage of making the build system be both standalone and integrated into a larger whole.  This is important to us since we want to use one build system for all libraries, whether they are integrated in or written by an external author.

I'm now working on building custom version of Android internals, for example an version of Android's SQLite classes that are based on the SQLCipher encrypted sqlite.  So I have to write non-recursive Android.mk files that are wrapping all sorts of weird build systems, like sqlite's.  I can't figure out how to make the Android.mk execute an arbitrary script, while this would be easy in a traditional recursive make system, from my experience.