# Parallelization of recursive jobs in GNU make

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing

I am looking for an elegant way for the parallelization of jobs in GNU make. Here is a sample of what I did so far. Make processes the directories dir-1, dir-2 and dir-3 in a serial fashion which is logical but not my intention:

```
SUBDIRS=dir-1 dir-2 dir-3

default: all

all:
  @for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do (cd $$dir; $(MAKE)); done

.PHONY: clean

clean:
  @for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do (cd $$dir; $(MAKE) clean); done
```

Is there a way to support parallel processing of these directories using the "-j" option without specifying specific targets for each directory?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SUBDIRS = a b c

default: all

$(SUBDIRS)::
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)

all clean : $(SUBDIRS)
```

Comment: Explanation on double-colons: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Double_002dColon.html

Comment: An explanation WHY is double-colon rule needed here would be nice. Having read the description, it isn't.

Comment: So it always executes, even when the subdir exists.

Answer (score 5):

This probably will not answer your question directly, but besides what the other answers suggest, I would recommend to look into non-recursive make techniques. That is truly an elegant way to parallelize build, although, depending on what are the existing Makefiles, can require significant effort.  Non-recursive make has advantages not limited to easy parallelization: it sees a complete dependency graph and so it does not need to build too little or too much, meaning faster (sometimes much faster) build times.

Some resources:

- [Discussion on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559216/what-is-your-experience-with-non-recursive-make)
- [The classic text about trouble with recursive make](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/)
- [Design of non-recursive makefile](http://sites.e-advies.nl/nonrecursive-make.html)
- [Implementation](http://github.com/dmoulding/boilermake)
- [Another implementation](http://code.google.com/p/nonrec-make/)
- [Benchmarks (quite outdated though)](http://www.kolpackov.net/projects/build/benchmark.xhtml)

Comment: Thx for these ressources. I'll put some effort into getting to know how make works. Actually I am not that familiar with it.

Comment: Design url is 404'ing

Comment: http://sites.e-advies.nl/nonrecursive-make.html might be an updated url

Comment: Yeah - it looks like it's the right updated URL, I have updated the answer

Answer (score 4):

I found that when using the :: (double-colon rule), I could not find a way to force order if there were any dependencies among `app`, `lib`, and `doc`.  After reading much of the GNU Make manual, I came up with the following rules to enforce the dependencies at the same time as having a generic recursive make.  Notice that the .PHONY rule is there to force make to enter the directory even though the directory already exists.

```
SUBDIRS = app lib doc

default: all

app: lib

.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)

all clean install: $(SUBDIRS)
```

Answer (score 3):

Are dir-1, dir-2 and dir-3 interdependent or independent?

I have a similar structure but dependence between the subdirectories so with that I preferred to just use parallel builds *within* each of the subdirectories. You'd get that via

```
## default to four parallel runs
MAKEFLAGS += -j 4  

all:
  @for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do (cd $$dir; $(MAKE) ); done
```

But another trick is to read up on `SUBDIRS` in the make manual -- you do not need the `for` loop as `make` can unroll this for you.  Try something like

```
## default to four parallel runs
MAKEFLAGS += -j 4  

SUBDIRS =    dir-1 dir-2 dir-3

$(SUBDIRS):  #whatever your depends here
             $(MAKE) -C $@
```

Comment: It's best not to hard code '-j 4' inside the Makefile. It will be passed to the child make via MAKEFLAGS when called with $(MAKE) if '-j n' is specified by the user on the command line.

Comment: Agreed in principle, in practice this was from a real Makefile where I am too lazy to always type 'make -j 4' yet want parallel builds -- and also see my note about the interdependence between sub-directories.

Comment: Try this - sets a default but doesn't clobber command line: MAKEFLAGS                      += -j 4

Comment: Do you know how make handles these $(MAKEFLAGS)? I think the number of simultaneous jobs is the number of processed directories multiplied by 4 in this case, or something like that. Thus, I would not forward the "jobs"-argument to child-makes. What do you think?

Comment: That is not my impression. I mod'ed an existing project with five SUBDIRS to use 'MAKEFLAGS += -j 4' and I got up to four compilations going.