# how to bring structure to Modern CMake include paths

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to use modern cmake and I've run into the issue where all my `#include` statements have no folders in them and it's confusing as all hell. [Here's an example](https://github.com/PeterMitrano/scratch)

Project structure:

```
root:
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - core
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - core.h
    - core.cpp
  - bin
    - bin.cpp
    - CMakeLists.txt
  - other_dirs
  - ...
```

Root CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(scratch)

add_subdirectory(core)
add_subdirectory(bin)
```

bin/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(x2_cli x2_cli.cpp)
target_link_libraries(x2_cli core)
```

core/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(core core.cpp core.h)
target_include_directories(core PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

I would like to write my include statements like `#include "core/core.h"`, but with this strategy I have to just write `#include "core.h"`. I think this is very confusing, because you get no sense of what header files belong to what libraries!

Is there a way to fix this which doesn't also allow me to `#include` things form other folders I'm not supposed to? For example `#include other_dir/bad.h` ideally should fail at compile time. Do I need a different directory structure? Maybe there's a CMake way to do it?

Just writing `target_include_directories(core PUBLIC ..)` is not good enough because it pollutes my include path, and it's misleading.

Comment: You probably need some sub-folders in your project structure (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360734/whats-a-good-directory-structure-for-larger-c-projects-using-makefile)). What I've often seen if you use something like `#include "core/core.h"` that your have something reflecting this in your folder structure e.g. via `include/core/core.h`.

Comment: One more example: [The Ultimate Guide to Modern CMake](https://rix0r.nl/blog/2015/08/13/cmake-guide/)