# Is this a good directory structure to maintain a large C++ project?

Tags: c++, cmake, directory-structure

I have been trying to figure out a good directory structure that is maintainable for large C++ projects. During my search I came across this resource here [link](https://api.csswg.org/bikeshed/?force=1&url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vector-of-bool/pitchfork/develop/data/spec.bs). If I loosely follow the structure stated in that document, it seems I get something similar to the following

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── build
│   ├── Executable-OutputA
│   └── Library-OutputA
├── cmake
│   └── *.cmake
├── docs
├── include
│   └── *.h
├── lib
│   ├── LibraryA
│   │   ├── *.cpp
│   │   └── *.h
│   └── LibraryB
│       ├── *.cpp
│       └── *.h
├── src
│   ├── ExecutableA
│   │   ├── *.cpp
│   │   └── *.h
│   └── ExecutableB
│       ├── *.cpp
│       └── *.h
├── tests
└── third_party
    ├── External-ProjectA
    └── External-ProjectB
```

- **build:** holds the outputted executables and libraries generated by the project
- **cmake:** holds all the cmake packages that the project may require
- **doc:** holds documentation files, typically doxygen
- **include:** holds public headers files (might not be needed, not sure)
- **lib:** holds all the libraries the user creates with their respective source and header files
- **src:** holds all the executable projects the user makes with their respective headers and source files
- **tests:** files to test both the executables and libraries
- **third_party:** any third party projects, libraries, ect. usually downloaded from online or cloned

I believe this is an appropriate structure for large projects, but I do not have too much experience with projects that produce more than 3 or 4 targets. I want to ask the community for feedback and if they agree with the structure laid out above, or have better suggestions.

Edit: I have not been able to find too many posts detailing multiple target outputs as well as third party dependencies for large projects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a good directory structure for larger C++ projects using Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360734/whats-a-good-directory-structure-for-larger-c-projects-using-makefile)

Comment: @SMMahmudulHasan I felt that my was different enough because I want to have multiple targets, not just an executable, or just a library. Also even in the answer, it says use cmake for large projects but does not elaborate on how to do so. I think that with all the complexity I have added with third party resources and such, my question warrants a different answer.

Comment: This seems pretty sane. You might also take a look into some of the available package managers for C++, such as [conan](https://conan.io/), instead of putting all third libraries into **third_party** folder.

Comment: There is no **universal** good directory structure for CMake project. Just select the one you find convenient and follow it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I agree. I just wanted feedback about this specific approach and its possible shortcomings that I may have missed.