# Recursive/Nestable build system?

Tags: build, makefile

Are there any existing build systems with the following criteria?

- Nestable/Recursive.  I.e. there is no "top" level build file like in CMake or (non-recursive) make or just about every other build system.
- In-source builds.  This is required for a build system to be cleanly nestable/recursive.
- Automatic dependency scanning for many languages
- Configuration files with declarative rather than imperative syntax
- Configuration file Syntax supports adding arbitrary custom build rules
- No IDE project generation bloat
- No showstoppers for cross-platform implementation
- Hash based change detection (or at least ~something) better than timestamps
- Free software

Basically, I want something that is up to the task of managing software build dependencies system-wide, but is still minimalist and efficient. I want a spiritual successor to make that is adoptable by a majority of the open-source world.  What comes the closest?

Comment: You may not want to have a recursive system, depending on what you mean by the term.  See [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/) for a very interesting read on this topic, and see also this other StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/559216/223837.

Comment: take a look at fab http://fabutil.org. It meets several of these requirements depending on specifically what you mean. Notably, it does "nestable" well, and has integrated dependency discovery, though currently only for a few languages (but the discovery facility is extensible)

Answer (score 1):

Tup looks interesting...

http://gittup.org/tup/

and djb redo:

https://github.com/apenwarr/redo/

and shake:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake

Comment: I read some more, and it looks like tup and redo both set up databases at some root level.

Comment: Oh, but wow, the tup dev actually has a toy linux distro that imports everything as git submodules and builds everything with tup!

http://gittup.org/gittup/

Answer (score 0):

Makepp comes close, and I have used it.  For some reason it doesn't have much traction, though... Potential downsides:

- Implemented in perl rather than a systems programming language, so fewer devs interested in hacking on it?
- Not in apt, so harder to take seriously
- Inherits syntax from Make; doesn't really enforce ONE correct way of doing things
- Slow builds
- Subdirectories don't inherit information from parents

Answer (score 0):

The ninja infrastructure looks interesting.  It isn't a standalone build system, but maybe it will catalyze someone into writing a very elegant front-end.  And perhaps CMake supporting it as a back-end will speed it's adoption.

http://martine.github.com/ninja/