# Makefile.am rebuilds entire project

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, autotools

I have a simple project:

https://github.com/spesmilo/obelisk

For some reason 'make install' causes my entire project to rebuild everytime. Also it seems like object files are getting built twice. I have no idea why.

'make' by itself is fine though.

Full output: http://pastebin.com/gvwi2bkN

```
~/obelisk> make; make; make install
Making all in include/obelisk
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/genjix/obelisk/include/obelisk'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/genjix/obelisk/include/obelisk'
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/genjix/obelisk/src'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/genjix/obelisk/src'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/genjix/obelisk'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/genjix/obelisk'
Making all in include/obelisk
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/genjix/obelisk/include/obelisk'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/genjix/obelisk/include/obelisk'
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/genjix/obelisk/src'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/genjix/obelisk/src'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/genjix/obelisk'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/genjix/obelisk'
Making install in include/obelisk
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/genjix/obelisk/include/obelisk'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/genjix/obelisk/include/obelisk'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/home/genjix/usr/include/obelisk/client'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 client/backend.hpp client/interface.hpp client/blockchain.hpp client/transaction_pool.hpp '/home/genjix/usr/include/obelisk/client'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/home/genjix/usr/include/obelisk'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 message.hpp zmq_message.hpp '/home/genjix/usr/include/obelisk'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/genjix/obelisk/include/obelisk'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/genjix/obelisk/include/obelisk'
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/genjix/obelisk/src'
depbase=`echo message.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
    /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"obelisk\ 0.1\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"genjix@riseup.net\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"obelisk\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -I.  -std=c++11 -DLEVELDB_ENABLED -I/home/genjix/usr/include   -I./../include -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/home/genjix/usr/etc\"   -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT message.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o message.lo message.cpp &&\
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
libtool: compile:  g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"obelisk 0.1\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"genjix@riseup.net\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"obelisk\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -I. -std=c++11 -DLEVELDB_ENABLED -I/home/genjix/usr/include -I./../include -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/home/genjix/usr/etc\" -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT message.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/message.Tpo -c message.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/message.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"obelisk 0.1\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"genjix@riseup.net\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"obelisk\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -I. -std=c++11 -DLEVELDB_ENABLED -I/home/genjix/usr/include -I./../include -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/home/genjix/usr/etc\" -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT message.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/message.Tpo -c message.cpp -o message.o >/dev/null 2>&1
depbase=`echo zmq_message.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
    /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"obelisk\ 0.1\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"genjix@riseup.net\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"obelisk\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -I.  -std=c++11 -DLEVELDB_ENABLED -I/home/genjix/usr/include   -I./../include -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/home/genjix/usr/etc\"   -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT zmq_message.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o zmq_message.lo zmq_message.cpp &&\
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
libtool: compile:  g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"obelisk 0.1\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"genjix@riseup.net\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"obelisk\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -I. -std=c++11 -DLEVELDB_ENABLED -I/home/genjix/usr/include -I./../include -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/home/genjix/usr/etc\" -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT zmq_message.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zmq_message.Tpo -c zmq_message.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/zmq_message.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"obelisk 0.1\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"genjix@riseup.net\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"obelisk\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -I. -std=c++11 -DLEVELDB_ENABLED -I/home/genjix/usr/include -I./../include -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/home/genjix/usr/etc\" -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT zmq_message.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zmq_message.Tpo -c zmq_message.cpp -o zmq_message.o >/dev/null 2>&1
depbase=`echo client/backend.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
    /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"obelisk\ 0.1\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"genjix@riseup.net\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"obelisk\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -I.  -std=c++11 -DLEVELDB_ENABLED -I/home/genjix/usr/include   -I./../include -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/home/genjix/usr/etc\"   -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT client/backend.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o client/backend.lo client/backend.cpp &&\
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
libtool: compile:  g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"obelisk 0.1\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"genjix@riseup.net\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"obelisk\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -I. -std=c++11 -DLEVELDB_ENABLED -I/home/genjix/usr/include -I./../include -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/home/genjix/usr/etc\" -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT client/backend.lo -MD -MP -MF client/.deps/backend.Tpo -c client/backend.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o client/.libs/backend.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"obelisk 0.1\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"genjix@riseup.net\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"obelisk\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -I. -std=c++11 -DLEVELDB_ENABLED -I/home/genjix/usr/include -I./../include -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/home/genjix/usr/etc\" -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT client/backend.lo -MD -MP -MF client/.deps/backend.Tpo -c client/backend.cpp -o client/backend.o >/dev/null 2>&1
depbase=`echo client/interface/interface.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
    /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"obelisk\ 0.1\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"genjix@riseup.net\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"obelisk\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -I.  -std=c++11 -DLEVELDB_ENABLED -I/home/genjix/usr/include   -I./../include -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/home/genjix/usr/etc\"   -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT client/interface/interface.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o client/interface/interface.lo client/interface/interface.cpp &&\
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
libtool: compile:  g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"obelisk 0.1\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"genjix@riseup.net\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"obelisk\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -I. -std=c++11 -DLEVELDB_ENABLED -I/home/genjix/usr/include -I./../include -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/home/genjix/usr/etc\" -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT client/interface/interface.lo -MD -MP -MF client/interface/.deps/interface.Tpo -c client/interface/interface.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o client/interface/.libs/interface.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"obelisk 0.1\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"genjix@riseup.net\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"obelisk\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -I. -std=c++11 -DLEVELDB_ENABLED -I/home/genjix/usr/include -I./../include -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/home/genjix/usr/etc\" -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT client/interface/interface.lo -MD -MP -MF client/interface/.deps/interface.Tpo -c client/interface/interface.cpp -o client/interface/interface.o >/dev/null 2>&1
depbase=`echo client/interface/fetch_history.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
    /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"obelisk\ 0.1\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"genjix@riseup.net\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"obelisk\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -I.  -std=c++11 -DLEVELDB_ENABLED -I/home/genjix/usr/include   -I./../include -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/home/genjix/usr/etc\"   -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT client/interface/fetch_history.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o client/interface/fetch_history.lo client/interface/fetch_history.cpp &&\
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
libtool: compile:  g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"obelisk 0.1\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"genjix@riseup.net\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"obelisk\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -I. -std=c++11 -DLEVELDB_ENABLED -I/home/genjix/usr/include -I./../include -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/home/genjix/usr/etc\" -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT client/interface/fetch_history.lo -MD -MP -MF client/interface/.deps/fetch_history.Tpo -c client/interface/fetch_history.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o client/interface/.libs/fetch_history.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"obelisk 0.1\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"genjix@riseup.net\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"obelisk\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -I. -std=c++11 -DLEVELDB_ENABLED -I/home/genjix/usr/include -I./../include -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/home/genjix/usr/etc\" -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT client/interface/fetch_history.lo -MD -MP -MF client/interface/.deps/fetch_history.Tpo -c client/interface/fetch_history.cpp -o client/interface/fetch_history.o >/dev/null 2>&1
depbase=`echo client/interface/blockchain.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
    /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"obelisk\ 0.1\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"genjix@riseup.net\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"obelisk\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -I.  -std=c++11 -DLEVELDB_ENABLED -I/home/genjix/usr/include   -I./../include -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/home/genjix/usr/etc\"   -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT client/interface/blockchain.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o client/interface/blockchain.lo client/interface/blockchain.cpp &&\
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
libtool: compile:  g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"obelisk 0.1\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"genjix@riseup.net\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"obelisk\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -I. -std=c++11 -DLEVELDB_ENABLED -I/home/genjix/usr/include -I./../include -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/home/genjix/usr/etc\" -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT client/interface/blockchain.lo -MD -MP -MF client/interface/.deps/blockchain.Tpo -c client/interface/blockchain.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o client/interface/.libs/blockchain.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"obelisk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.1\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"obelisk 0.1\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"genjix@riseup.net\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"obelisk\" -DVERSION=\"0.1\" -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -I. -std=c++11 -DLEVELDB_ENABLED -I/home/genjix/usr/include -I./../include -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/home/genjix/usr/etc\" -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT client/interface/blockchain.lo -MD -MP -MF client/interface/.deps/blockchain.Tpo -c client/interface/blockchain.cpp -o client/interface/blockchain.o >/dev/null 2>&1
depbase=`echo client/interface/transaction_pool.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
```

Comment: `libtool` is invoking the compiler twice to build an object that can be used 'statically' (or in archives), and an object suitable for use in a shared library. `configure` typically accepts `--disable-shared` or `--disable-static` if this is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

I used to have these problems, too, when I used [recursive makefiles](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/) as you are doing.  Going to a non-recursive make system solved them.  Your build system for that project isn't that complex.  You might find more concrete advice (and other possible solutions) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559216/what-is-your-experience-with-non-recursive-make) on how to go about doing it.

Comment: I put everything in my root Makefile.am. Still didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you are giving `make` twice in the command `~/obelisk> make; make; make install`?
`make` compares the timestamps and build only the files which require rebuilding. Its very common that there will be `all` dependency on `install`, I mean `install: all` but if once the targets are already build they won't be built again.

Comment: read the output. make doesn't rebuild anything. but when i type make install it rebuilds the entire project from scratch. this happens everytime i type make install.

Comment: Can you post the Makefile