# Why does Make re-link when I call make in a subdirectory?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm having trouble understanding something in `make`. I have a main `Makefile` calling another `Makefile` in a subdirectory. I would like `make` not to re-link when **nothing has changed**. But it seems that the sub-directory `make`, wherever something was done or not, triggers a new linking.

Here is the main `Makefile`

```
NAME = app

CC = gcc

SRC = app.c

OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): get-libaf $(OBJ) app.h
    $(CC) -L./libaf/ -laf -o $@ $(OBJ)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

get-libaf:
    $(MAKE) -C ./libaf/
```

And here is my library in the subdirectory ./libaf/ `Makefile`

```
NAME = libaf.a

CC = gcc

SRC = af_app_helper.c af_app_argv_parser.c af_app_memory.c

OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): libaf.h
    $(CC) -c $(SRC)
    ar rc $(NAME) $(OBJ)
    ranlib $(NAME)
```

When I run the main `Makefile`, this is the output:

```
user@machine $ make
make -C ./libaf/
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
gcc -L./libaf/ -laf -o app app.o
user@machine $ make
make -C ./libaf/
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
gcc -L./libaf/ -laf -o app app.o
```

but when I remove the libaf dependency (`get-libaf`), it only says:

```
user@machine $ make
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

...which is what I would like to have when I haven't changed a thing between `make` commands. I even checked the timestamps of all the files and none was modified/edited/touched. Same with the library.

I understand that `make` re-links when there is a change in a source file or dependency. Here, I don't understand why the "sub-make" is doing this.

Could someone explain why `make` re-links and how this can be prevented. I want to keep the `get-libaf` dependency though, so I can update it and run `make` only once for the whole project.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The obligatory link: http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/

Comment: And a potentially-useful SO link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559216/what-is-your-experience-with-non-recursive-make

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to read this !

Comment: BTW even if you do decide to stick with recursive make, this article might help you understand some of the problems you're facing and give you ideas for solving them.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a beginner and this is not easy to find on Google (or SO) as 'make' is such a common verb and the keywords hard to find. Thanks for the link !

Comment: BTW, is there an "easy" way to keep my structure and make it behave like I want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will work to have `$(NAME)` depend on the actual file `libaf/libaf.a` instead of a phony target (`get-libaf`) if you add a rule for `libaf/libaf.a` (in the top-level makefile) that invokes `make -C libaf`.

(The issue is that there's no `get-libaf` file with a timestamp for make to compare against, so it has to assume the result is "modified" after each run.)

Comment: Oh I get it now ! This is a simple and efficient solution for my problem. I'll keep the file about recursive Makefiles, I'm sure it will be useful for larger projects.