# Check if files were compiled with certain flags in Makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have multiple files in my project which are compiled to object files using either `-fPIC` or without this option. When compiling those files for the use in a shared library, this option is necessary, else not. Thus when I compile the project into a shared library, this option is necessary.
Nevertheless I never am sure if the last compilation was done into the shared library or not. If not, and I want to compile it into the shared library, the compilation fails, and I have to delete the generated object files. The recompilation of those object files takes quite a lot of time, which I would like to avoid.
Is there a way for the makefile to detect if the object files have been compiled with or without this option right at the beginning, so that either the compilation can continue, or both have to be recompiled, without generating either an error or spending a lot of time in an unnecessary recompilation loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell, with something like objdump, if an object file has been built with -fPIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340402/how-can-i-tell-with-something-like-objdump-if-an-object-file-has-been-built-wi)

Comment: @KarstenKoop: How can I include f.ex. the first answer into my makefile?

Comment: What is causing `-fPIC` to appear/disappear between builds? Normally this would be something you'd change in the Makefile itself, triggering a full rebuild.

Comment: @arc_lupus you could make a shell script that checks the object files for -fPIC and then calls your makefile with an argument indicating whether or not to recompile with -fPIC or not (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make).

Comment: @Sneftel: It depends on which Makefile I am calling

Comment: That's not a good organization. If you do have multiple makefiles, they should not produce output in the same place.

Comment: What I usually do to differentiate files built with certain options is to make the build output folder's name depend of those options. Like `build_fPIC` and `build_no_fPIC` per example.

Comment: similarly for release vs. debug builds, etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: "Is there a way for the makefile to detect if the object files have been compiled with or without this option"

Short answer: No

Long answer: if source files can be build with different options and you have to have access to the different builds at the same time, then you must have several output folders. And the makefiles must generate them in the correct folder.
Say something like this for a simple debug/release ("-g" flag) :

```
|
-src
-include
-BUILD
  |
  -obj
  | -debug
  | -release
  -bin
    |-debug
    |-release
```

Of course, this approach has limitations. For example, if you need to have both "debug/release" and "PIC/not PIC", then you will need 4 output folders.

You can also mix my approach with the one proposed by @BasileStarynkevitch (generating specific names).

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach could be to have your own convention about object files and their naming. For example, file `foo.c` would be compiled into `foo.pic.o` when it is position-independent code, and into `foo.o` when it is not. And you could adapt that idea to other cases (e.g. `foo.dbg.o` for a file with DWARF debug information, compiled with `-g`). You could also use subdirectories, e.g. compile `foo.c` into `PICOBJ/foo.o` or `PICOBJ/foo.pic.o` for a PIC object file, but this might be less convenient with `make` ([beware of recursive makes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/562380/841108)).

Writing appropriate rules for your `Makefile` is then quite easy.

Be aware of other [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) systems, e.g. [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/).